# Finding the first occurrence after a null value for each id

Tags: t-sql

There's two tables: A) all the valid dates in a time frame B) list of events id and respective date in which it occurred.

| dt_util |
| --- |
| 2022-05-01 |
| 2022-05-02 |
| 2022-05-04 |
| 2022-05-05 |
| 2022-05-06 |
| 2022-05-07 |

| id_event | dt_event |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2 | 2022-05-01 |
| 3 | 2022-05-01 |
| 1 | 2022-05-02 |
| 3 | 2022-05-02 |
| 1 | 2022-05-04 |
| 2 | 2022-05-04 |
| 3 | 2022-05-04 |
| 1 | 2022-05-05 |
| 2 | 2022-05-05 |
| 1 | 2022-05-07 |
| 2 | 2022-05-07 |

The desired result is to find the minimum date after the last "missing" (NULL) date for each ID, something like this:

| id_event | min_dt_event |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-07 |
| 2 | 2022-05-07 |
| 3 | 2022-05-01 |

I've been trying using FIRST_VALUE and ROW_NUMBER but no luck so far. I know it might be possible going through a loop for both tables, but it's not feasible with the real dataset.

```
    -- Creating temp tables
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP_EVENTS
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP_DATES
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_EVENTS (
        id_event smallint,
        dt_event date
    )
    
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_DATES (
        dt_util date
    )

    INSERT INTO #TEMP_EVENTS VALUES 
            (1, '2022-05-01'),
            (2, '2022-05-01'),
            (3, '2022-05-01'),
            (1, '2022-05-02'),
            (3, '2022-05-02'),
            (1, '2022-05-04'),
            (2, '2022-05-04'),
            (3, '2022-05-04'),
            (1, '2022-05-05'),
            (2, '2022-05-05'),
            (1, '2022-05-07'),
            (2, '2022-05-07')
            
    INSERT INTO #TEMP_DATES VALUES 
            ('2022-05-01'),
            ('2022-05-02'),
            ('2022-05-04'),
            ('2022-05-05'),
            ('2022-05-06'),
            ('2022-05-07')

    -- Creating fictional table where all ids matches all dates
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP_ID_EVENTS
    SELECT DISTINCT ID_EVENT, DT_UTIL 
    INTO #TEMP_ALL_DATES 
    FROM #TEMP_EVENTS A 
    LEFT JOIN #TEMP_DATES B
    ON 1 = 1
    
    -- Minimum date after a null date
    SELECT 
         A.ID_EVENT, [DT_UTIL], [DT_EVENT],
         FIRST_VALUE([DT_UTIL]) OVER (PARTITION BY A.[ID_EVENT] ORDER BY [DT_EVENT] DESC) AS MIN_DATE
    FROM 
        #TEMP_ALL_DATES A
    LEFT JOIN 
        #TEMP_EVENTS B
    ON  
        A.id_event = B.id_event
    AND A.dt_util  = B.dt_event
    WHERE dt_event IS NULL
```

Comment: Why for `id = 2`, the date is not `2022-05-04` when `2022-05-02` is missing ?

Comment: Because 2022-05-06 is also missing for both id = 1 and id = 2, so 2022-05-07 is the minimum date after the last missing null.

Comment: OK. Then what is the logic for `id 3` ?

Comment: There's no null values between 2022-05-01 and 2022-05-04 for id=3 and it doesn't show up again after, therefore it's the minimum value. But I would accept an answer if its just null for the minimum date if id=3.

Comment: I need to know the minimum value for each id going backwards in an uninterrupted series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-query using `row_number()` to generate a running number for dates in `#TEMP_DATES`.

Then by joining to that sub-query on `date` and using `lag()` to check for `row_number rn`, it should be different of 1 if there isn't any missing date.

Lastly just get the `max` to get the date of the "last missing null"

```
with cte as
(
    select *,
           flag = case when d.rn <> 1 
                       and  lag(d.rn) over(partition by e.id_event 
                                               order by e.dt_event) <> d.rn - 1
                       then 1
                       else 0
                       end
    from   #TEMP_EVENTS e
           inner join
           (
               select rn = row_number() over (order by dt_util),
                      dt_util
               from   #TEMP_DATES
           ) d             on e.dt_event = d.dt_util
)
select id_event, 
       dt_event = max(case when flag = 1 then dt_event end)
from   cte
group by id_event
```

Result:

| id_event | dt_event |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-07 |
| 2 | 2022-05-07 |
| 3 | null |

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad55808c7b7efd0d00eda5ea569401b0)